# Why does Django give me a 404 error for only one url pattern?

Tags: python, django

I'm following thenewboston's Django tutorial and no one seems to be running into this problem.

I have created a music app with an index view which works fine. Now I want to create detailed views for music albums.

music.urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    # /music/
    path(' ', views.index, name='index'),

    # /music/21/
    path('music/<int:album_id>/', views.detail, name='detail'),
]
```

music.views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

# Create your views here.
def index(request):
return HttpResponse("<h1>This is the music app homepage")

def detail(request):
return HttpResponse("<h2>Detail " + str(album_id) + "</h2>")
```

I do get a few warnings in Visual Studio Code stating that Django is unable to import some modules. But if that was the cause then url/music should also return a 404 error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[URL](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/urls/) parameters are in `kwargs` aka named arguments

```
def detail(request, album_id):
    return HttpResponse("<h2>Detail " + album_id + "</h2>")
```

also you should change your URL path as you have already included URLs to top lvl URLconf ( otherwise it would be accessible through /music/music/{id}

```
 path('<int:album_id>/', views.detail, name='detail'),
```

I would suggest you going over [Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/intro/tutorial01/) tutorial

Answer (score 0):

Use snakecase for naming in python. So change the filename and import properly.

Answer (score 0):

change your path to this because in music.urls you are already passed '/music'

```
    path(r'<int:album_id>', views.detail, name='detail'),
```

Comment: That didn't change anything, unfortunately.

ing the URLconf defined in website.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
music/
The current path, music/1/, didn't match any of these.

this is the response I get